# Popup div hidden at the end of the data table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Currently we are facing an issue related to a div that hides at the end of a data table that we are using in our system. The popup div is working fine from the top to the last 7th child of our data table data after that popup div hides.

Is it possible to show the hidden part of the popup/modal div?

let me share some pictures for more clarification.

1. This image shows that the popup div is working fine from top to the last 7th child of the data table

[image]

2. This image shows that the popup div is hiding at the end of the data table.

[image]
[image]

Let me know when you need further details and please share the related solutions I will be thankful

Comment: Can you also provide the code for a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Otherwise it will be impossible to help you, we can't magically guess what your code looks like.

Comment: Your last two images show that your popup is a child of the table wrapper div.  You need to either make enough space at the end of the table wrapper, which will push down the page count etc (not a good idea).  Or, you need to move your popup out of the wrapper, most likely to top level (directly inside `<body>`).   You can do this when you render the popup or move it after using javascript.

Comment: please post the code snippets which you are using.